# How to locate and read the inbox messages

Tags: support

I got a flag that I have 2 unread inbox messages. I have many posts. How can I locate and read these new messages without going through all my posts which is a time consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each message in your 'inbox' is a hyperlink to where it comes from: simply clicking on the message title/text summary should take you to the relevant question or answer.